# Dividend result with leading zero is 2.5 instead of 3. Why?

Tags: php, math, integer

Why the following code displays **2.5** instead of **3**:

```
$a = 012;
echo $a / 4;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable is being interpreted as an octal.  Per the docs:

> To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero). To use
>   hexadecimal notation precede the number with 0x. To use binary
>   notation precede the number with 0b.

Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score 1):

Starting a number with 0 like that means octal (base 8). So octal 12 = decimal 10.